# Inserting values instead of formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write up my first macro.

This is what I've done so far. It opens a file and will copy formula's in cells not their values. Could you please help me with solving this issue.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, file As String

file = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

Range("A1").Value = file
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file
'copy from ThisWorkbook
Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'To This
'Set wb2 = Workbooks(2)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(file)

'Copy Data from Wb1.Sheet1 to Wb2.sheet1

wb2.Sheets("Questions").Range("C9:C200").Cells.Copy  Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D200")


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only copy values using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667749/how-to-only-copy-values-using-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the copy row to the following:

```
    Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D200").value = wb2.Sheets("Questions").Range("C9:C200").value
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
wb2.Sheets("Questions").Range("C9:C200").Cells.Copy
Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D200").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats   'Will paste the formulas and number format
Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D200").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats  'Will paste the formatting
```

Comment: I believe the opposite is wanted, they would like the values and not the formulas. Therefore I think your second line should replace xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats to xlPasteValues.

Comment: @user2731076 Yes, you are right. Really `weird question title`. And the accepted answer also verified OP's intention. Lol. Thanks for pointing that out. :)